# Copy file from internal server to remote server in IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, networking

I have an application written in c# that after creating a pdf file, needs to save this pdf file to a virtual folder in a remote server. The server is in DMZ and I already created two users in both servers with the same permissions. The two servers are not in the same network. I'm able to access a dummy pdf file using

```
string stempSourceFilespec = "https://ServerName/VirtualFolder/dummy.pdf";
b = file bytes;
//Here I write the bytes
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(stempSourceFilespec, b)
```

, but I'm having problems when copying a pdf file to the same virtual directory. The user I'm using has full permissions over that folder.

This works internally when using \servername\folder\, but doesn't work when I try to save to a remote virtual directory. Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe you should set up FTP on your remote server.

Answer (score 0):

try convert virtualpath to phyicalpath in a handler, such as
system.web.httpserverUtil.mappath

http://asp.net.bigresource.com/Uploading-files-to-server-and-saving-outside-virtual-path-bMVjFTYf4.html#l9LpkWyji

http://forums.iis.net/t/1157234.aspx